# Ubuntu load kernel from MicroSD card

Tags: 14.04, sd-card

I have a noob quesion.

So my friend gave me a MicroSD card containing a linux kernel. I mounted this MicroSD card onto my ubuntu machines and can see the following contents :

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/mnt$ ls -lrt
total 208896
-rw-r--r-- 1 osboxes osboxes 209715200 Jan  1  2001 image-full-galileo-clanton.ext3
drwx------ 4 osboxes osboxes     32768 Jan  1  2001 sensor
-rw-r--r-- 1 osboxes osboxes   1987504 Sep 30  2014 bzImage
-rw-r--r-- 1 osboxes osboxes    279670 Sep 30  2014 grub.efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 osboxes osboxes   1697473 Mar 17  2015 core-image-minimal-initramfs-clanton.cpio.gz
drwx------ 3 osboxes osboxes     32768 Mar 26  2015 boot
osboxes@osboxes:~/mnt$
```

I see the compressed `bzImage` kernel . Is it possible for me to see everything that is packed inside this kernel image home folders etc ? How do i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i overcame my nOObness and can simply mounting the .ext3 filesystem . I copied the .ext3 file to a new m2 directory and then mounted it via the following command:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo mount -t ext3 image-full-galileo-clanton.ext3 /home/osboxes/m2
osboxes@osboxes:~$ cd m2/
osboxes@osboxes:~/m2$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  sbin  sketch  sys  tmp  usr  var
```